# Difference between implicit and explicit intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm confused about the difference between **implicit** and **explicit** intents. What is the purpose of implicit and explicit intents, and why are these concepts used?

I am new to Android applications, so please provide some examples.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Explicit Intent: Explicit intent names the component.
2. Implicit Intent: Implicit Intents have not specified a component.

E.g: The java class which should be called Implicit intent asked the system to perform a service without telling the system which java class should do this service.

Answer (score 45):

## Implicit activity call

With an intent filter you create action for your activity so other apps can call your activity via an action:

```
<activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="http"/> 
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

## Explicit activity call

You make a call that indicates exactly which activity class to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityABC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Here's an additional reference](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/471.html)

Comment: Is it a copy&paste form here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272699/what-is-the-different-between-explicit-and-implicit-activity-call-in-android/20728603? u could reference