# Multiple activities competing one intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I got an interview question.....

How to specify which Activity to be launched from an implicit intent, when there are multiple activities competing to execute the intent, without requiring user intervention.

My answer to this question is to use proper intent-filter within every activity, but it just sounds wrong..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating an Intent **you can pass explicit component name. i.e. class name**. Only that component will now receive the intent.

example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RequiredActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

If you don't specify the exact component, Android will smartly let user choose one of the components that handles the intent.

example:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

If you want to go through all the components that handle the intent, yourself instead of letting android show choices to user, you can do that too:

example:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    List<ResolveInfo> infoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo ri : infoList){
        ActivityInfo ai = ri.activityInfo;
        String packageName = ai.packageName;
        String componentName = ai.name;

       // you can pick up appropriate activity to start 
       // if(isAGoodMatch(packageName,componentName)){
       //     myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,componentName));
       //     startActivity(myIntent);
       //     break;
       // }

    }
```

I got six Activity matches for above code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it denoted that "without requiring user intervention", so we cannot just createChooser and let the user to pick an activity to run...

Comment: When you say `You can pass explicit component name`, doesn't it becomes _explicit_ intent. When I read the [Difference between explicit and implicit Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813586/difference-between-implicit-and-explicit-intents), it said that implicit Intents don't specify any component. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) also said `In implicit we do not name a target (i.e the field for the component name is blank).`Are you trying to say something different? I couldn't understand. Doesn't the question asks for `implicit intent`?

Comment: So is the correct answer that android will choose itself in the intent is _implicit_? Also just curious to know that is there any predefined criteria mentioned in docs based on which it chooses?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I thought we can use intent-filter with specific data, category or action so that the system will pick an activity base on these criterias. While if the answer is this, the question should probably be "if we have multiple intents, how can an activity receive a specific one and perform what it is desired to".

Comment: @S.D. i'm curious as well so one more question:Have you tested the third one ever?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Also the question denoted that "multiple activities competing to execute the intent", so I assume that all these activities have intent-filters that fulfill the intent's criteria.

Comment: @S.D. I see the third option, Interesting! so the for loop will go through all possible activities and pick the most proper one to run?

Comment: @Sherman_Meow the third example, lets you handle the selection yourself.