# Do we need extra information about activity class in manifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am talking about `<action android:name="packagename.ImagePagerActivity" />`. It's seems unnessesary to add it, because the application works fine without it. But why do some developers write such reference?

```
<activity
            android:name=".adapter.imageview.ImagePagerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="packagename.ImagePagerActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<action android:name="packagename.ImagePagerActivity" />` Says that you can call this Activity ***Implicitly***

Like

```
Intent intent = new Intent("packagename.ImagePagerActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Read more about [What is the different between Explicit and implicit activity call in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272699/what-is-the-different-between-explicit-and-implicit-activity-call-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you mention

you can invoke your activity from

```
intent.setAction("packagename.ImagePagerActivity");
```

and start activity.

Implicit call instead of mentioning current activity and target activity explicitly.