# App crashes when using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I got a >very< simple program, that crashes, when I try to change the activity.
On my fragment_app_launch.xml there only is a Button (id: question_cat_button_1):

AppLaunch.java

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch,
                container, false);

        Button b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.question_cat_button_1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity");
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.pthuermer.juraquiz.QuizActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quiz" >
</activity>
```

logcat-error:

```
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity }
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1671)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at com.pthuermer.juraquiz.AppLaunch$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(AppLaunch.java:75)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-13 21:09:54.602: E/AndroidRuntime(13753):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash.

Comment: so this is your activity you are trying to launch?

Comment: its only the fragment-class.

Comment: stacktrace? is this my log cat aswell?

Comment: what happens when you do `new Intent(getActivity(),QuizActivity.class)`

Comment: now it works! can you explain why the other way was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity");
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.pthuermer.juraquiz.QuizActivity");
```

small "q"

[Differences in implicit and explicit Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272699/what-is-the-different-between-explicit-and-implicit-activity-call-in-android)

You can find out a lot about implicit `Intents` easily by searching Google but typically for starting an `Activity` inside your own app it is easier with an explicit `Intent` as you used to get it to work.

Comment: same, it says "juraQuiz stopped"

Comment: But that's not the exception. That's the message you will get with every crash. Clear out the logcat and post the new logcat from the new crash.

Comment: `new Intent(getActivity(),QuizActivity.class)` worked. but why?

Comment: it says: fatal exception. i can't post the log cat in a comment

Comment: No, I would never want you to post your logcat in a comment. I meant by editing your post. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working. I have edited with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Java is case-sensitive, so `com.pthuermer.juraquiz.QuizActivity` and `com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity` are not the same, that is why you get `ActivityNotFoundException`. It should be:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the **ACTION** of the Intent to `"com.pthuermer.juraQuiz.QuizActivity"`.
I guess you want to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String).

Answer (score 0):

Hey change your intent to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.pthuermer.juraquiz.QuizActivity.class);
```