# intent.getAction() and intent.getType() returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to receive data from other apps when share button is pressed. App is shown in the chooser and when I press the app, it  opens but I can't get text!!

Here's my splash screen if it makes any sense.

**Cover.java**

```
public class Cover extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(Cover.this,MainActivity.class));
    this.finish();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
onCreate(...)
setContentView(....)
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    Log.d("nikesh"," "+action); //this  prints null
    Log.d("nikesh"," "+type); //this prints null
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent);
        }
    }


   private void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    Log.d("khee",sharedText);      //these are 
    if (sharedText != null) {      //not printed
        Log.d("khee",sharedText);
textView.setText(sharedText);
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: intent.getIntent() returns null ? maybe a typo in method name ? did you mean intent.getType ?

Comment: @RobertEstivill ya sorry, It's getType();

Comment: Docs are surprisingly helpful: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getType()

Comment: Same thing, you need to set the type on the Intent object.

Comment: oh let me try it now

Answer (score 0):

You are using an explicit intent, which doesn't get resolved by the system and IntentFilters.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Cover.this, MainActivity.class));
```

If you still want to start the activity using the class, you will have to call [`setAction` on the Intent.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String))

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Cover.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
startActivity(intent);
```

or disregard the explicit part, and just set the action

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ya, I did what you said, Now, ma getting getAction() value as android.intent.action.SEND but getType() is returning null

Comment: Because you need to set it by calling `setType`. Explicit intents don't set default values. Read the following answer to understand the difference between explicit and implicit intents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914881/android-implicit-intents-vs-explicit-intents

Comment: I pass intent.setType("text/plain"); is this the correct value? I not getting shared text :(

Comment: Because you are not setting any Intent extra with the key Intent.EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: I'm not getting you! will you please update your answer ?? I'm a complete beginner I followed this https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html
I have done like this in my Cover activity 
Intent intent = new Intent(Cover.this,MainActivity.class); //which is just a splash screen
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();

Comment: You need to call `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatever text")` to add "whatever text" to the bundle in the intent, with the key "Intent.EXTRA_TEXT". That is the key you will use later on to retrieve "whatever text" out of the Intent bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the splash screen. txt is the key here.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Cover.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra("txt",getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
```

MainActivity.java

```
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

   if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent);
        }
    }


  }
    public void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText =   getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("txt");
    if (sharedText != null) {
        textView.setText(sharedText);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much **@Robert Estivill** to make me find problems!!